# Longtable with dynamic footer

Tags: longtable

In the example  below, what I want is for the foot row, which `longtable` adds on every page break, to be the opposite background color of the row above it. It seems that the footer code is evaluated only once. I guess it's stored in a box. Is there a way to force `longtable` not to evaluate the code until it inserts it into the page?

Bonus question: if I do not add `\\` before the line commands (`thickline`, `thinline`), I get some "noalign" error and the document fails to compile. This forced me to write really ugly "fixup" code, i.e. `\\[-3.1ex]`, otherwise I get empty lines in the table. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

```
\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, colortbl}
\usepackage[usenames, svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcounter{curRowNum}
\newcommand\incRowNum{\stepcounter{curRowNum}}

\newcommand{\headcol}{\rowcolor{red!25}}
\newcommand{\rowcol}{\rowcolor{red!10}}
\newcommand{\thickline}{\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{0.1em}{0pt}{0pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}}
\newcommand{\thicklinec}{\arrayrulecolor{purple}\specialrule{0.1em}{0pt}{0pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{curRowNum}{0}
\begin{longtable}[!hc]{>{\incRowNum}c}
  \caption{MWE longtable coloring test.}\label{tbl:long_color} \\
  \thickline
  \headcol \multicolumn{1}{c}{ID} \\
  \thickline
\endfirsthead
  \caption*{Table \ref {tbl:long_color} - Cont.: MWE longtable coloring test.} \\
  \thickline
  \headcol \multicolumn{1}{c}{ID} %
  \pgfmathparse{isodd(\thecurRowNum)}%
  \typeout{[Head] Odd: \pgfmathresult - Row: \thecurRowNum}%
  \ifnum1=\pgfmathresult\relax%
    \\ \thickline %
  \else%
    \\ \thicklinec %
  \fi%
\endhead
  \pgfmathparse{int(isodd(\thecurRowNum))}%
  \ifnum1=\pgfmathresult\relax% 
    \\[-3.1ex] \thickline %
  \else%
    \\[-3.1ex] \thicklinec \rowcol %
  \fi%
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\incRowNum}r}{\emph{End}}%
  \pgfmathparse{int(isodd(\thecurRowNum))}%
  \ifnum1=\pgfmathresult\relax%
    \\ \thicklinec %
  \else%
    \\ \thicklinec %
  \fi%
\endfoot
        \thecurRowNum \\
\rowcol \thecurRowNum \\
        \thecurRowNum \\ \newpage
\rowcol \thecurRowNum \\
        \thecurRowNum \\
\rowcol \thecurRowNum \\ \newpage
        \thecurRowNum \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: If `[!hc]` doesn't generate an error, sorry for not catching that, it doesn't do anything, delete it!

Comment: Ah, too bad. I'm trying to figure out a solution with xtabular now.